# Clean regex to match inner text

Tags: regex, innertext

I'm parsing markup to match the inner text of tag elements using the following regex.

```
(?<=<*>)[^<]+(?=<[^>]*>)
```

I'd like to optimise this to remove matches on white space.
eg: >space \n  etc <

eg:

```
<div>
     <div>TargetMatch</div>
</div>
```

Targeted Hits:

1. TargetMatch

Actual Matchs:

1. "     "
2. TargetMatch

Any ideas?

Slyi

Comment: With the regex above you are matching everything that's between two tags - what exactly is it that you want to do with the new one ? Can you provide example input string and expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

Pattern: `>\s+<`

Replacement: `><`